# Summing multiple matrices in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a file containing 60 matrices. I would like get the mean of each value across those 60 matrices.

so the mean of the [1,1] mean of [1,2] across the matrices.

I am unable to use the mean command and am not sure what's the best way to do this.

Here's the file: `https://dl.dropbox.com/u/22681355/file.mat`

Comment: What do you mean by not being able to use the `mean` command?

Comment: the file contains 60 separate matrices if I type mean(results_foptions) then I get the error: ??? Undefined function or method 'sum' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Error in ==> mean at 28
  y = sum(x)/size(x,dim);

Comment: Actually, the file you linked to does not include 60 separate matrices, but one cell-array which includes those 60 matrices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 % concatenate the contents of your cell array to a 100x100x60 matrix
 c = cat(3, results_foptions{:});

 % take the mean
 thisMean = mean(c, 3);
```

To round to the nearest integer, you can use

```
 roundedMean = round(thisMean);
```

Comment: but what I would like to do is actually take the mean across the cell arrays with the same location

Comment: so basically take the mean of the first entry in each cell then the mean of the second array and end up with a single matrix with the means of each entry

Comment: great, thank you. in the end is there any way to round to the nearest integer?

Answer (score 1):

You should put all the matrices together in a 3 dimensional (matrix?), *mat*, as:

```
mat(:,:,1) = mat1;
mat(:,:,2) = mat2;
mat(:,:,3) = mat3;
etc...
```

then simply:

```
mean(mat, 3);
```

where the parameter '3' stipulates that you want the mean accros the 3rd dimension.

Answer (score 0):

The mean of the matrix can be computed a few different ways.

First you can compute the mean of each column and then compute the mean of those means:

```
colMeans = mean( A );
matMean = mean(colMean);
```

Or you can convert the matrix to a column vector and compute the mean directly

```
matMean = mean( A(:) );
```

Comment: but what I would actually like to get is a single matrix with the means of each entry across the cell arrays

Comment: @user1723765 ok, you didn't make that clear in your original question